Microsoft SQL Server 2000. Consulta días en columnas recuento
Microsoft SQL Server 2000
Dispongo de una tabla de reservas, reservas hoteleras, donde guardo entre otra mucha información:
Desde | Hasta | Ocupación | Origen
Desde: Fecha inicio estancia en el hotel
Hasta: Fecha finalización estancia en el Hotel
Ocupación: Número de personas (una persona, dos personas ... que disfrutan del apartamento)
Origen: lugar de origen de las personas que están alojadas.
Necesito:
Por días, contar el número de personas que están de vacaciones por cada Origen

Con esa información necesito realizar el informe que adjunto, solo se me ocurre hacer bucles y acumuladores para lograrlo. Alguien me puede orientar

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Esto se puede lograr con un agregado condicional. Esto es gracias a que las funciones de agregado no solo reciben columnas como parámetros sino que pueden recibir cualquier expresión incluyendo CASE.
Aquí un ejemplo básico de como hacerlo.
DECLARE @FechaDesde datetime,
        @FechaHasta datetime;
SELECT @FechaDesde = '20240301',
       @FechaHasta = '20240331'
SELECT Origen,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 0, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 0, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia01,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 1, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 1, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia02,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 2, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 2, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia03,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 3, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 3, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia04,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 4, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 4, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia05,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 5, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 5, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia06,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 6, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 6, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia07,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 7, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 7, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia08,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 8, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 8, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia09,
        SUM( CASE WHEN DATEADD( dd, 9, @FechaDesde) >= Desde AND DATEADD( dd, 9, @FechaDesde) < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia10
FROM TablaReservas
WHERE Desde < @FechaHasta
AND   Hasta > @FechaDesde
GROUP BY Origen;

Ahora bien, si además quieres hacerlo dinámico porque no sabes cuantos días tendrás, puedes usar código dinámico. En este caso uso 3 variables para poner el código. Dos son estáticas que incluyen la primera y última parte de la sentencia SELECT. La segunda es la parte dinámica que estará repitiendo un patrón pero cambiando ciertos detalles.
DECLARE @SQL1 varchar(8000),
        @SQL2 varchar(8000),
        @SQL3 varchar(8000);

SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT Origen';
SET @SQL2 = '';
SET @SQL3 = REPLACE( REPLACE( '
FROM TablaReservas
WHERE Desde < @FechaHasta
AND   Hasta > @FechaDesde
GROUP BY Origen;'
            , '@FechaDesde', QUOTENAME( CONVERT( varchar(8000), @FechaDesde, 112), ''''))
            , '@FechaHasta', QUOTENAME( CONVERT( varchar(8000), @FechaHasta, 112), ''''));

DECLARE @n int = 1;

WHILE @FechaDesde <= @FechaHasta
BEGIN
    SET @SQL2 = @SQL2 + REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( ',
       SUM( CASE WHEN @FechaDesde >= Desde AND @FechaDesde < Hasta THEN Ocupacion ELSE 0 END) AS Dia@m'
            , '@n', @n)
            , '@m', RIGHT( @n + 100, 2))
            , '@FechaDesde', QUOTENAME( CONVERT( varchar(8000), @FechaDesde, 112), ''''));

    SET @FechaDesde = DATEADD( dd, 1, @FechaDesde);
    SET @n = @n + 1;
END


PRINT @SQL1;
PRINT @SQL2;
PRINT @SQL3;

EXEC( @SQL1 + @SQL2 + @SQL3);

